# Which class to use for this static method, StringBuffer or StringBuilder?

Tags: java, multithreading, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

For the following code, which class should I use in a static method, `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`?  Based on the API, `StringBuffer` is thread-safe, but `StringBuilder` is not.

```
public static String getString(int[] arrs) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  //1
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();    //2
    for (int i : arrs) {
        sb.append(i);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This same question has been asked many, many times.

Answer (score 6):

It's a method-local variable, you won't have concurrent access there... so use StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

Why worry about thread safety with the code you've shown though? If your StringBuilder isn't being used in a way that requires having to worry about thread safety, then don't spend the overhead required for it needlessly. Use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, if its a local variable and isn't handed out to another thread, there is no need for any threading protection. Your StringBuilder is completely local to the method.

Answer (score 0):

use StringBuilder because there is loacal variable method